# New quickblox with maven compile dependencies. giving error on startCall

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, quickblox, quickblox-android

Im using the quickblox in one of my applications.
its dependencies have been added using

app build.gradle =>

```
// start quickblox, online dependencies, from remote repository, aar files
compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:${rootProject.qbSdkVersion}@aar"
compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:${rootProject.qbSdkVersion}@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:${rootProject.qbSdkVersion}@aar"
compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:${rootProject.qbSdkVersion}@aar"
compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:${rootProject.qbSdkVersion}@aar"
compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-location:${rootProject.qbSdkVersion}@aar"
compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:${rootProject.qbSdkVersion}@aar"
```

note `qbSdkVersion=2.5`

prject build.gradle =>

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}}
```

It all works the build dependencies are fetched, infact session and login also works.

The application crashes on startCall() due to following error..

```
    02-23 21:18:31.671 30766-2911/com.prontoitlabs.pocquickblox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-212
Process: com.prontoitlabs.pocquickblox, PID: 30766
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.prontoitlabs.pocquickblox-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libjingle_peerconnection_so.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
    at org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.<clinit>(PeerConnectionFactory.java:39)
    at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.PeerFactoryManager.initializeFactoryFieldTrials(PeerFactoryManager.java:109)
    at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.PeerFactoryManager.initPeerConnectionFactory(PeerFactoryManager.java:83)
    at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.PeerFactoryManager.access$100(PeerFactoryManager.java:11)
    at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.PeerFactoryManager$1.run(PeerFactoryManager.java:59)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.LooperExecutor.run(LooperExecutor.java:73)
```

I do not understand this nativelibs error, i mean i've not included the dependences using libs/*.jar etc ive used gradle dependences.

i use the following gradle `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`

Help!...

Comment: and yes i know its because its not able to find the damn jingle.so but it should have come along with the gradle deps as you do get it when you add the same files as libs/*.jar dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to video chat sample https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc. You should put .so files in jnilibs/ directory under src/main.

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines in your project **build.gradle**

```html
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
     }
    }
```